# Open source UI framework(s) for manipulating core data in UITableViewController's

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview

Does anyone know of an existing open source UI framework that would help with repetitive tasks like adding or editing core data objects with a UITableViewController with a fairly standard (but hopefully customizable) look and feel?  When you are dealing with a lot of objects, it gets repetitive and redundant quickly.

If not, I'm considering starting my own project, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It sounds like you want an iPhone version of Core Data Bindings which doesn't exist yet for the iPhone. If someone has an open source version of something like this, I'd be interested too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

The closest you can get is the Apple provided NSFetchedResultsController. The sample code is basically the same for every app, with a few tweaks here and there (Of course this is no UI help).

Jeff LaMarche has a good implementation of the delegate methods that are a little better than what you find in the official docs.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/core-data-navigation-based-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, I think it's still relevant today as I recently undertook a similar search, and I guess since the question was answered, there are now frameworks available.

There are a few solutions out there (some premium, like [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com/)) but as for open source, personally I chose [zdetailkit](https://github.com/plan44/zdetailkit) for my project. It's based around a customized UITableViewController and cells.

It's pretty easy to get up and running with and provides the data bindings you're looking for. The samples bind to NSUserDefaults, but it works perfectly with Core Data entities.